# How to present an empty cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My task is simple basically for most of you, but obviously im doing something wrong here.

I have a two table view controllers that I want to populate their cells based on some object status. Im working with core data so also doing `fetchResultController` too.

in one of the view controllers I can change the status of the cell object (not the actual cell, the object that is populating the cell), and whenever that happened I want to delete this cell from the table view. In that view controller I want to present only the cells that the object that is populating them have the `status = 0`. but I dont want to delete the ones that was deleted, just to change their `status to 1`, and then in some other view controller to present them if they have the `status = 1`.

So what im doing is:

Whenever the `commitEditingStyle` is getting called:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        Target *target = [self.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        target.status = @1;
    }

    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didDeleteObject)]) {
        [self fetchData];
        [_delegate didDeleteObject];
    }

}
```

Now what I had in mind is in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method to add a condition when im returning a cell like this:

```
if ([target.status  isEqual:@0]) {
        return cell;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

since I want to present only the cells that have the status 0...

So now obviously I cannot enter this table view because I have to return a cell in this method and not done, how can i just say that if the statues of the object target is different than 1 so dont present the cell?

other code solutions will be great too :)

thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to filter out fetch request with a predicate

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Target"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status == %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

When you set your status attribute to 1, FetchedResultsController will automatically delete cell from the tableView, but the object will not get deleted. You don't have to do anything in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. And in your other tableView, set the predicate to only fetch `status == 1`.
Also, make sure to save the managedObjectContext when you change the attribute's value.

```
Target *target = [self.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

target.status = @1;

NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Save Failed! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }
```

Comment: awesome bro! this works, just a minor thing - whenever I terminate the app and run it again I do see the same objects with the status 1 that i deleted before...where do I say that the status I want to fetch is 0..?

Comment: @nickshmick Glad it worked! It should be in FRC delegate method `- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController`. Also, when you delete, did you save the `managedObjectContext`? Ideally, FRC should automatically update the tableView for you when add, delete, update, etc, if it is setup right. Check this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-nsfetchedresultscontroller--cms-21681) on how to use FRC. It's really helpful!

Comment: i am calling fetchData in the viewDidLoad. yes when I delete the object in tableView commitEditingStyle im doing CoreDataStack *stack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack]; and then [stack saveContext]

Comment: but now because i added the lines to save it in the commitEditingStyle, so its actually deleting the objects

Comment: @nickshmick You shouldn't have to call `[self fetchData]` in viewDidLoad or anywhere else to populate the tableView. FRC delegate methods will take care of it for you. And you can't delete an object unless you call `[context deleteObject:object]`...

Comment: hi, you said in the other view controller i can create the predicate to fetch object with status = 1...how can i do that? this is the line in the fetch request     NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status == %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
so where do i say status = 1?

Comment: @nickshmick Try with `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in this way.

You have to set a dynamic `numberOfRowsInSection:`, depending on how many `Target` has `status` property equal to `@0`
So, in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you will return the cell only if the status is `@0`.

For me is better if you split the dataSource in dataSource with `target.status = @0` and others.

A right way is this

```
// This is the point where you have an update dataSource array (not splitted)
updatedDatas = [Manager getLatestData];
if (dataSource.count > 0)
    [dataSource removeAllObjects];

[updatedDatas enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Target *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([obj.status integerValue] == 0)
       [dataSource addObject: obj];
}];
updatedDatas = nil;

// This is the numberOfRowsInSection:
- (NSInterger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return dataSource.count;
}
```

In the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you will now use the dataSource `NSMutableArray` with a simple `objectAtIndex:` to access the correct element

Comment: I want to try your suggestion with splitting the dataSorce. So I thought in the viewDidLoad I will fetch the objects from fetch result controller that have status =0 and copy them to a local array call statusZeroObjects (for exmple), and in the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath I will use this array. but when i think of if in the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath method im fetching the objects from nsfetchresultcontroller, cant i there just fetch the objects that have the attribute status with the value of 0?

Comment: You can without splitting the dataSource, but you always have to check if the current element in the array has `status` = @0. I think is better if you split the dataSource once and then you use it without always check if a condition is true or false.

Comment: Ok, so can you add the for loop or if there is other way to copy only the objects with the status 0 please? I though of something but the syntax is wrong. Like if(int i =0; i< self.fetchresultcontroller.fetchedObjects.count; i++) {if(fetchresultcontroller objectatindex:i isequal:0 ) { self.activeObjects at index:i equal:self.fetchresultcontroller.fetchedobjects objectatindex:i}}

Comment: so now in the cell for row i added: Target *target = [self.activeTargets objectAtIndex:(int)indexPath]; I had to cast it since the objectAtIndex for a nsmutable array is expecting int....but now i have targets but i cant see them in the table view...something wrong now with the population of the cells

Comment: You can not cast indexPath to an int type. You have to use the `row` property of indexPath: `Target *target = [self.activeTargets objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];` This one works if you are not creating more than one section in this table

Comment: still :/ - http://d.pr/i/15mQF/4LOulTmW here is a screenshot where you can see that my table view is empty, but in the consol i print the number of objects i have...which is 8

Comment: I don't how it is possible. Try to set a breakpoint in cellforrow and see what happens

Comment: @LucaD If he's using the FetchedResultsController, there's no need to create dataSource to populate the tableView. FetchedResultsController will populate it for you.